# Error happens during file open in asp.net on wep page?

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I try to open the file and update content in the file, it gets sum error like this.

My code

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Request.QueryString("log") = "no" Then
        pinfo.Text = "Invalid Username / Password"
    End If
    Session.Clear()

    Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim FileReader As StreamReader

    Dim Countstr As String

    FileReader = File.OpenText("/dmkg/Counter.txt")

    Countstr = FileReader.ReadLine

    FileReader.Close()

    Countstr = Countstr + 700

    FileWriter = File.CreateText("/dmkg/Counter.txt")

    FileWriter.WriteLine(Countstr)

    FileWriter.Close()
 End Sub
```

Check the code and tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Pass Correct PATH in OpenText Method not File Name

## [File.OpenText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Eg:**

```
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt" 

FileReader = File.OpenText(path)
```

So Make sure your file path is correct.

If it's stored in server then you need to use Server.Mappath()

```
FileReader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("/dmkg/Counter.txt"))
```

## [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**To Enable a Access**

To grant ASP.NET write access to a path,

- right-click the file in Explorer,
- choose "Properties" and select the Security tab.
- Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group (typically
  {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6).
- Highlight the needed account, and check the boxes for the desired
  access.

Comment: Use Server.MapPath("/dmkg/Counter.txt"). Mark helpful if it's helped you

Comment: It give error like this  Access to the path 'D:\Hosting\11094770\html\dmkg\Counter.txt' is denied.

Comment: To grant ASP.NET write access to a path, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6). Highlight the needed account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Comment: Can you please Check now